# How Can I Get Parent Document's Id on Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

There is `doc` document in `details` collection, and it is child of `{id}` document in `col` collection.

What I want to do is, when user changes fields in `col/{id}/details/doc`, I wanna update fields in `col/{id}`.

```
exports.onChanged = functions.firestore
    .document('col/{id}/details/doc')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

     .....
```

However, I don't know how to get `{id}` in JavaScript.

Is there way to get `id` as String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) object to get values of all wildcards in your path as shown below:

```
exports.onChanged = functions.firestore
    .document('col/{id}/details/doc')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      console.log(context.params.id);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to receive the `{id}` of the document by calling the .parent method. In your case it might be two parents up, since the first parent is the collection.

So to access the {id} of the document would be:

```
change.after.ref.parent.parent.id
```

Hope it helped